# primefaces jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

**Context**: Trying to use jquery ui plugins (tabs and dialog) in a primefaces application directly from javascript (due to a certain requirement).

**Problem**: Getting 'length undefined' and 'undefined not a function' errors on the calls. More specifically, $("#id").tabs() is throwing the error.

**What I did**: search in stackoverflow; checked $.fn.* and $.ui.* in the console; surprisingly a lot of ui plugins are available (datepicker, droppable, selectable) but dialog and tabs seem to be missing. $.ui.version is 1.11.3. I tried using outputScript and directly <script> tags to include jquery ui, but none seemed to include these plugins; tried noConflict.

**Additional info**: It worked at some point intermittently.. not sure what caused it to work and what is preventing it from working now. Spent a lot of time troubleshooting this.

Advance thanks for your time and shall drop additional info if required.

Comment: PrimeFaces contains a customized (subset) of the jQuery-UI components. The others have to be added by you. And make sure you use them from a compatible version. Compatible with the jQuery version that PrimeFaces uses.

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje, your answer is helpful in understanding. I had already added the jquery-ui.js 1.11.3 and it is compatible with 1.6+ onwards. $.ui.version has the value of 1.11.3 which tells me that the one I included with script tag has loaded, but has not resulted in tabs and dialog being included. Is there a way I can include these plugins separately? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can include them separately in the normal jquery-ui way... (I have no clue in detail, sorry)

Comment: Thanks again @Kukeltje, including separately solved the problem. Not sure how to accept the answer which is a comment :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces contains a customized (subset) of the jQuery-UI components. The others have to be added by you. And make sure you use them from a compatible version. Compatible with the jQuery version that PrimeFaces uses.

Including them should be done like you normally would include separate jquery-ui components or jquery-ui compatible  ones by normally loading them via a javascript tag

Comment: This answer saved my day. Just for clarification: I downloaded the zip for 1.8.23 jquery-ui (which seems to be bundled with primefaces 3.5) which contained the jquery.ui.tabs.js and jquery.ui.dialog.js (and corresponding css files). Including them in the project made all the functionality to work. Thanks!